# How to divide web pages in blocks with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, pug, sails.js

I am starting developing with Sailsjs and I would like to know how to divide a webpage into differents blocks.

for example  :

in **layout.jade** i have

```
doctype html
html(lang="fr")
head

body
    div(class='container')
        div(class='row')
            div(class='col-md-12')
                block header
                    h1 header
                div(class='row')
                    div(class='col-md-8')
                        block content
                    div(class='col-md-4')
                        block right
                block footer
```

then in my **controller1/index.jade** i have

```
extends layout
    append content
        p
            some content
```

So when I type http://myserver.com/controller1/index in the browser, it works.

How to append some code in the **block right** form the result of another controller ? (I don't want to append some code to the **block right** directly in the **controller1/index.jade** file, to make the file as shorter as possible).
So I guess we can call another method of the controller inside the jade file ?
For example i would like to put a code like :

```
append right
    =call('controller2/action1')
```

at the end of the **controller1/index.jade** file.

The purpose of my question is to figure out how divide the html parts of a webpage like we can do it with php using include method (for example).

Thank you

Benjamin

Comment: What do you mean "from the result of another controller"? Are you asking how to add the contents of another jade file to the `right` block within `index.jade` or are you wanting to load the content via a function?

Comment: yes I would like to append the content of a jade file but how to do this if this jade file has loop or variable inside ?

Comment: You should simply be able to use `include`. Any loops and variables will be evaluated after the partial is inserted so to speak. Alternatively if the partial needs to be pre-evaluated for some reason, then you can do so and pass it in as a string to a variable using `!{variable}` in the template instead. I could write up a more definitive answer but I am still unsure as to the context with which you need the partials included.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But it means that If I type the url /controller/index I have to generate all variables need by the partial in the controller/index. And it seems difficult to do it. Is there a way to call a controller inside the .jade file ? Or how can I do it (generate the variable in calling the second controller inside the /controller/index ) easily  ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to make the function call and add the result as a variable as above or pass the required function to the template from the first controller. But I would have to question how effectively you have structured your models and controllers if you are needing to do this. You might want to post a more comprehensive example of what exactly you are trying to achieve.